# IPP batch install of CUPS managed printers in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, printing, printers, intel-ipp

In our Department we're using CUPS and **when we install a new printer we have to configure IPP ports** (along with printer drivers etc.) for the computers to talk to CUPS.

Since we have many machines with different O.S. (Win 7 to 10 and MacOS) **for the Windows environment I wrote an installer which copies driver files and runs a batch file to actually install the printer.**

All goes well until it comes to the point where the Printer is to be installed into the system, where sometimes **we experience some different and unpredictable behaviours**.

Most annoying issue is when the batch command returns "Port Unknown" errors.

The batch command I'm using is:

```
cd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\KX_740830_UPD_signed_EU
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /f".\KX7.4_v7.4.0830\64bit\OEMSETUP.INF" /b "Kyocera_BN_Musica" /r "http://147.162.42.95:631/printers/Kyocera_BN_Musica" /m "Kyocera TASKalfa 4012i KX" /Z
```

Most of times it works. Sometimes not.

So, since we want users to perform the installation independently, I'm looking forward to an hint about if **there's a better, safer, more stable and predictable method to install IPP printer ports and/or Printers via a batch file.**

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: You seem to be out of sync with your Double quotes (opening/closing) or is it perhaps a copy/paste error? Should this part `/b Kyocera_BN_Musica"` not be `/b "Kyocera_BN_Musica"` ?

Comment: Ops! Yes, it was a copy/paste error in this post; it was correct in the batch file, indeed. Edited.